# Unable to connect to a repository at URL - Versions SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have been using Tortoise SVN on a windows machine successfully and have moved to a Mac. `The respository it pulls from is svn://example.com:3690 with a username and password.`

When I copy the above into Versions for mac it replies with:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://username@example.com'
```

Where `svn://username@example.com` is what I typed in. Note it forces me to put that username in when I type my username in the username box.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

- `svn://username@example.com` is perfectly valid and correct URL
- If you can't connect to repo, it's connectivity problem, obviously. Check it by connecting to repo by hand (telnetting to host's port), if it will failed - firewall's settings on your side or on repository's host